# Parity default "token deployment" Dapp issue

Tags: dapps, parity, bug

I'm using Parity 1.4.6 testnet on OSX.
When I'm trying to test default token deployment Dapp,

[image]

transaction sending responds with "Transaction cost exceeds current gas limit. Limit: 5183626, got:60000000. Try decreasing supplied gas."

[image]

Why is token deployment so expensive? Is it possible to avoid such error for this Dapp?

Comment: Added to 1.5 milestone: https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/4080#issuecomment-271087992

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed from Parity version 1.4.9